# Typescript Structure array length not working

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a class with an internal structure that is an array of a structure that I have:

```
Fields: DataField<any>[] = new Array<DataField<any>>();
```

I then have a function that adds the structure into the array with the key from the structure used as an index.

```
AddField(FieldInfo:DataField<any>):void {
    let FieldName:string = FieldInfo.Name;
    this.Fields[FieldName] = FieldInfo;
}
```

In trying to test that this works, I can see that the structure is created properly, but the length value is not returning correctly.  Console.log output:

```
console.log(TestObject.Fields);
  [ Name: DataField { Name_: 'Name', Size_: 32, Value_: 'My Name' },
    Age: DataField { Name_: 'Age', Size_: 2, Value_: 33 } ]
```

My test is then:

```
expect(TestObject.Fields.length).toBe(2);
```

But this test fails and reports the length is 0.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)
Expected value to be (using ===):
  2
Received:
  0
```

Using the console.log on the TestObject.Fields.length shows 0 as well.

```
console.log(TestObject.Fields.length) 
  0
```

Comment: try `console.log(Object.keys(TestObject.Fields).length) `

Comment: `this.Fields[FieldName] = FieldInfo`, you index a string into an array, do you even array bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an element by index doesn't change the length:

[image]

## Fix

Use methods like `push` `slice` etc that exist on arrays.

Comment: The reason `x['a'] = 'a'` does not change the length is because it  just adds `a` as another property on array instance `x`, it does not update the underlying contiguous memory block that `x` points to, arrays are just javascript objects with numeric properties, and javascript allows you to add any properties to existing objects

Comment: @basarat I still want to be able to access the element by the key name as this code is from a library function that is building the array.  If I use the push() onto the array, can I always count on the new entry being the last entry, so I can change the index to the key?  I think I might be better to move this into a Dictionary object.